# How do I get rid of this red dot

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have tried to look online but I haven't found anything. There is a red dot on my screen in only this blender file, and only in the layout tab. It isn't an annotation and it isn't an object, and it is in the same place regardless of how I move or rotate, it isn't attached to anything on the axis. Does anyone know what happened?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like the origin of your object called Cube.044, no?

Comment: Press the period (full stop) key on the numpad. That should bring the object into view and you can then scroll the view out to see where it's actually located in your scene.